# Git status no longer displays when branch is ahead of remote repository by x commit

Tags: git

So I set up a new remote git repo using the following lines:

```
git remote add origin [link]
git push origin master
[enter password]
```

In my previous repo, when I make a new commit and check status, it will tell me that my branch is ahead by x commits if I forgot to use git push. However, this new repo no longer shows this when I use git status.

Can anyone tell me how to fix that?

Thanks,

Comment: I think you need to set up the branch to track the remote branch with `git push -u origin master`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The branch is not tracked. You should add add tracking: git branch --set-upstream master origin/master.
[Make an existing Git branch track a remote branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520650/how-do-you-make-an-existing-git-branch-track-a-remote-branch)